# whats the best platform to build a static websites with localization

Tags: static, localization

I have a requirement where in the application is static but need localisation .

Can someone suggest what should be right framework to build this. Just HTML/Jquery or any JS frameworks like next.js or something else

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build using Rails as there are lot of cms plugins are available. 
Try this https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine

Comment: For a static web site, I'd be wanting a client-side solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for you:
https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/step-step-guide-javascript-localization/